# Horovod torch estimator prepare_batch error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytorch, horovod

I'm trying to make a horovod torch estimator for a spark pipeline, but I'm getting an error while trying to fit the data and I don't know/understand the cause.
I've left the full stack error [here](https://pastebin.com/upte3TmU), but the final trace is as follows:

```
[1,0]<stderr>:Traceback (most recent call last):
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
[1,0]<stderr>:    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
[1,0]<stderr>:    exec(code, run_globals)
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/task/mpirun_exec_fn.py", line 52, in <module>
[1,0]<stderr>:    main(codec.loads_base64(sys.argv[1]), codec.loads_base64(sys.argv[2]))
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/task/mpirun_exec_fn.py", line 45, in main
[1,0]<stderr>:    task_exec(driver_addresses, settings, 'OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK', 'OMPI_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_RANK')
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/task/__init__.py", line 61, in task_exec
[1,0]<stderr>:    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 432, in train
[1,0]<stderr>:    'train': _train(epoch)
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 373, in _train
[1,0]<stderr>:    inputs, labels, sample_weights = prepare_batch(row)
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 306, in prepare_batch
[1,0]<stderr>:    for col, shape in zip(feature_columns, input_shapes)]
[1,0]<stderr>:TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Unfortunately, I don't really know how to give a minimal reproducible example, but I'll try to give the most relevant and minimal information possible to understand the context.

I'm working on a google colab notebook.

I created the estimator following the [documentation](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spark_include.html), like so:

```
import horovod.spark.torch as hvd
from horovod.spark.common.store import DBFSLocalStore
import shutil
import uuid

uuid_str = str(uuid.uuid4())
work_dir = "/dbfs/horovod_spark_estimator/"+uuid_str

from torch import optim
# Setup store for intermediate data
store = DBFSLocalStore(work_dir)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1.0e-3)

torch_estimator = hvd.TorchEstimator(
  store=store,
  num_proc=1,
  model=model,
  optimizer=optimizer,
  feature_cols=['Windows'],
  label_cols=['Labels'],
  verbose=1)
```

And the model is from this [repo](https://github.com/logpai/deep-loglizer), which is a basic LSTM in pytorch with some minor customizations. I also changed the requirements to use the most updated libraries.

The Dataframe fed to the fit function is like so:

```
+--------------------+------+---+
|             Windows|Labels| id|
+--------------------+------+---+
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2...|     1|  0|
|[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2...|     1|  1|
|[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2...|     1|  2|
|[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2...|     0|  3|
|[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...|     0|  4|
|[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...|     0|  5|
|[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...|     0|  6|
|[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...|     0|  7|
+--------------------+------+---+
```

Which is an array/vector of 10 ids and 1 label per window.

### My attempts to solve this issue

My first hypothesis was that, by looking at the error log, it looks like there is a mismatch between the input data and the model definition. If so, i don't understand how the mismatch could be possible, since the model expects as features the list of ids and a label of 1 or 0 for the whole window (list).
Thinking that it might be caused by the column names, I also tried changing them to exactly the name expected when using the normal torch dataloader, but with no success.

The second thing that stood out was that *NoneType object*, as if horovod isn't taking or finding the correct data or structure to pass the model.

I tried looking on the web for similar situations, but it seems like horovod isn't widely used, so I found little to nothing useful in helping me.

Any help in finding a solution to this would be greatly appreciated, but I'm also open to any alternative to horovod that can integrate a torch model into a spark pipeline or just be fed a spark dataframe.

### EDIT 1:

Thanks to @pSoLT I managed to get past the NoneType Error by setting the input shapes in the the constructor of hvd.TorchEstimator (in my case `input_shapes=[[-1,10]]`).
Unfortunately, I immediately stumbled upon another one:

```
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/task/__init__.py", line 61, in task_exec
[1,0]<stderr>:    [1,0]<stderr>:result = fn(*args, **kwargs)[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 432, in train
[1,0]<stderr>:    [1,0]<stderr>:'train': _train(epoch)[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 374, in _train
[1,0]<stderr>:    [1,0]<stderr>:outputs, loss = train_minibatch(model, optimizer, transform_outputs,[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 468, in train_minibatch
[1,0]<stderr>:    [1,0]<stderr>:loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels, sample_weights)[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/horovod/spark/torch/remote.py", line 351, in loss_fn
[1,0]<stderr>:    [1,0]<stderr>:loss = calculate_loss(outputs, labels, loss_weights, loss_fns, sample_weights)[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:NameError[1,0]<stderr>:: [1,0]<stderr>:free variable 'loss_fns' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope[1,0]<stderr>:
```

As I mentioned in the comments, I'll play around more if I have the chance, but I'll try switching to SparkTorch for the immediate future.

Comment: I discovered sparktorch as an alternative. In case I won't find a solution with horovod, I might consider switching to it

Comment: one of the arguments to zip() is None. Judging by the fact that you've correctly passed feature_cols to the constructor of hvd.TorchEstimator it looks like you also have to pass input_shapes. Also- check if feature_cols are not None.